# How to learn Shape's ID from shape

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I have a C# written COM-component which is inserted into a Shape on a PowerPoint slide. 
Question: How to learn shape's ID from the COM-component?

PS: sorry for my english.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "inserted into a shape".  Can you explain further (or better, post a bit of code).

Comment: So, i have a class inherited from UserControl. This class is registered for COM-interop and it have COM-register and COM-unregister methods. 
In PowerPoint I going to Developer->Other controls and selecting my class from the list. After that, i can place my user control to the presentation's slide as a shape.
And I have a little problem: I need to know shape's ID, which assigned by PowerPoint to my shape.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're placing the control manually and now just need the ID for other purposes, make sure the shape is selected, press ALT+F11 to open the VBA IDE, press Ctrl+G to open the Immediate window and type this into it:

```
? ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Id
```

The shape's id will be printed on the next line